# Softaculous installer.php

Tags: php, web-hosting

I am currently trying to install Softaculous on a web server (*we use Hosting Controller Panel*). I have an issue when running the `installer.php` file as directed in the instructions on the Softaculous web site.

The instructions say to open cmd and run `C:\path\to\php.exe C:\softaculous\installer.php`

When I do this I am given several error messages but the main issue I see is the `installer.php` is looking in the wrong directory (*an older install of PHP*) for ionCube loaders. Here is what I believe is the relevant portion of the command.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.6> php.exe C:\softaculous\installer.php
```

> Failed loading **C:\PHP\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll**
>
> Failed loading C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found. in Unknown on line 0*

You will notice that in bold the installer is trying to load PHP from a directory that I didn't specify, can anyone tell me why or how I might go about fixing this.

I have sought help from Softaculous and all they could tell me is PHP is not installed correctly.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer I have been working on this problem for over a month.

Comment: The ionCube Loader is an engine extension and specified in the main php.ini file with a zend_extension directive and an absolute path. Perhaps PHP is seeing an old ini file from a previous install or you have not edited the correct php.ini. I'd be inclined to remove all traces or PHP then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

use **ampps** http://www.ampps.com/

ampps have **softaculous** in it for **windows**